# May I call greetings between people who don't know each other well an "exchange of politeness"?

Tags: collocations

What can I call a situation when people don't know each other well, but just say hello to each other our of courtesy, so to speak? Can it be called *exchange of politeness* by analogy with *exchange friendly visits*?

**EDIT** Google Ngram shows *exchange of courtesies* is in order of magnitude more common. The same goes for *exchange of civilities*. Does it mean what I am talking about?

Comment: As you've obviously discovered, the "standard" form is an *exchange of **courtesies***. The equivalent for *politeness* would need to be pluralised to ***politenesses*** - which is credible, and does occur (rarely), but it's just too much of a mouthful to ever become "popular". Equally, although some native speakers might try to make it a little "easier" by going for the singular form, most others will recognize this as "wrong", so it won't catch on.

Comment: ***Exchange of pleasantries*** is much more common than any of the above (according to Google Ngram and my own anecdotal experience).

Comment: If all they do is greet each other, and don't stop to chat, one could say they *exchanged greetings*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merriam Webster provides the following sentence as an example in its article on **[civility](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/civility)**:

> They greeted each other with the usual **exchange of civilities**.

I must say that [the COCA corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) provides only one instance of "*exchange of civilities*" (none for "exchange of politeness").

Here's an interesting NGram:

[image]

There's also **exchange of amenities** - here's how it stacks against our record holder, **courtesies**:

[image]

Comment: Yes, Google Ngram shows exchange of civilities is common nevertheless: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=+exchange+of+civilities&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexchange%20of%20civilities%3B%2Cc0

Comment: And - yes, Ngram doesn't find exchange of politeness either. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @olegst - Thanks for the upvote, but it's usually a good strategy to wait a day or two before accepting an answer - this way, more answers will accumulate. I'm not a native speaker - they might come up with good example sentences. (0:

Comment: The first word that popped into my head was niceties. "Let's dispense with the niceties and get down to business."

Comment: @ColleenV - Nice! You might post that! I also thought of "they exchanged formal greetings".

Comment: I will think about it. I'm a little troubled that the dictionary definitions for nicety aren't quite the way I understand it in this context and I want to do some more poking around before I write an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure you really need to back up the substance of the answer *(No, "exchange of politeness" isn't idiomatic)* with frequency charts. It seems to me it simply reflects the fact that in the specific context. ***pleasantry, courtesy, civility*** are all *countable nouns that can easily be pluralised*. It's true ***politenesses*** does in fact exist, but it's a bit of a mouthful. And the singular doesn't work at all (we don't have *an exchange of **courtesy***), so native speakers just aren't likely to use either version.

Comment: According to Google Ngram, ***exchange of pleasantries*** is many times more common than any of the above.

Comment: The OP should wait 2-3 days before selecting an answer, especially when the only answer is from a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 3):

No, in contemporary native English it is called "an exchange of pleasantries." A Google Ngram confirms my native knowledge that this is much more common in our time then "exchange of civilities."

Note the Oxford Dictionary:

> [Pleasantry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/pleasantry):
>
> (usually pleasantries)
>
> An inconsequential remark made as part of a polite conversation: 
>   *'after an exchange of pleasantries, I proceeded to outline a plan'*
>
> More example sentences
>
> And off we both went through the rain, pleasantries exchanged and honour satisfied.
>
> After the introductions were done they exchanged pleasantries with Caitlyn who answered politely to all of them.
>
> Johnson attempted to start conversation with some pleasantries but Bill was not very talkative.

The [same dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/civility) gives one example sentence with *exchanging civilities*, but Google Ngrams confirms that *pleasantries* is much more common these days.

[image]